# JSON path expression to fetch keys of nested objects

Tags: python, json

what is the JSON path expression to fetch "item1" , "item2" without knowing in advance the names of these keys.

```
{
"item_group" : "This is item group",
"items": {
"item1": {
  "name1": "value1",
  "name2": {
    "value2": "value2"
  },
  "name3": {
    "param1": "This is param1"
  }
},
"item2": {
  "name11": "value11",
  "name22": {
    "value22": "value22"
  },
  "name33": {
    "param2": "This is param2"
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? what error are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `dict["items"].items()`. It will return a list of key/value tuples. For an example iterating over the keys:

```
for key, _ in dict["items"].items():
    pass
```

Comment: @Coder - I wanted a single line JSON path expression if I can to evaluate the object keys.  I did try with for..in loop and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

for..in loop worked!

```
for(var prop in obj) {
   console.log("Key_Name: " + prop);
}
```